# Is ImageIO write() a blocking method?

Tags: java, asynchronous, javax.imageio

In an application I'm developing in java, I am using the ImageIO API to scale images, then write them to a directory and then inform a web server that the images are ready to be used. The last call before sending a signal to the web server is the method ImageIO.write() but the web server cannot find the generated images at that moment. ( Few milliseconds latter the web server is able to see them. ).

What I suspect is that ImageIO.write() is running asynchronously. I've searched a lot but i couldn't find if ImageIO.write() is a synchronous or asynchronous operation. If ImageIO.write() is not blocking the flow of the program, is there a non-hacking way to make it wait till the image has been written to the destination directory ?

Comment: AFAIK, it is a blocking call ... can you share some code and some moe details regardig how you signal the webserver

Comment: Basically it works like this. The web server application sends a request for a scaled image towards my java application that does the scaling. That is over HTTP since my java application has jetty embedded. In Jetty's handleRequest I'm generating the new scaled image and save it to the filesystem. After that happens the jetty java application responds to the ( waiting ) web server indicating that it has finished saving the new scaled image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine that `ImageIO.write` isn't blocking.

My "assumption" is based on the fact that ImageIO.write can throws exceptions, which suggests, even if it as writing in the background, it would need to block until the write was finished in order to throw the exceptions.

It could be a buffering issue?

Try and do a `while (!file.exits()) Thread.sleep(25)` or something has a stop gap

Comment: Tried that myself too it didn't yield any results since as it seems the file does exist.

Comment: Sooo...I'd imagine it has something to do with the time it takes for the web server to be able to see the changes to it's own virtual context (ie any new files that might have been added).  It might be worth while adding in a forced delay (Thread.sleep(...)) starting out small and slowly getting larger until you can find the sweet spot where the web server can actually recognize the new file.  Or check what the web server is doing when you return as it might actually be a problem at that end :P

Comment: The file does exist, the write seems to take a little while, maybe because network drive or similar slow IO. Doing while and checking if file exist returns true always, but it doesn't mean that the file is ready to be read. I'm seeing the same behavior with ImageWriter.write. Looks non-blocking under certain conditions.

Comment: @TinusTate I can't see that either `ImageIO.read` or `ImageIO.write` are non-blocking in anyway.  They both throw `IOException`, which means that they must wait till the end of the process before returning, otherwise, how would they know if the operation was successful or not.  It's possible that there is disk and network buffering in place that are operations beyond the scope of the API

Comment: Yes i agree @MadProgrammer , i browsed through the JPEGImageWriter and write does set a thread lock. But it is weird that we both have the same problem, that write returns before the file is written. The network drive and/or IO buffering might indeed be the problem here.