# Forcing server to wait because image haven't finished writing to disk

Tags: java

I have a website that when a user uploads a PDF file, it gets sent to the server, does some PDF rendering, and creates a .png file to display as PDF preview thumbnail.

The problem is when the .png is created, the write to disk is slower than the whole execution, which causes the image to show on the site as an error because it tried to access an image that isn't there (because the code finished before write to disk is finished).

I added a `Thread.sleep(2000)` after the .png creation and it seems to fix the problem. Now my question is, for my situation would `Thread.sleep(2000)` be the best code to use? I don't know if that code could effect multiple users accessing my site and uploading files.

Let's say UserA uploads a file while UserB browses normally. After UserA uploads a file, does UserB experience the 2 second delay?

Is there a better way for me to pause the code execution in a situation like this?

EDIT: Added code. I am using PDF-Renderer as my library: https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer

```
public static void convertPDFtoImage () throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile (new File (rep.pathSamplePDF), "r");
    FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel ();
    ByteBuffer buf = fc.map (FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size ());
    PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile (buf);

    PDFPage firstPage = pdfFile.getPage(1);
    Rectangle2D r2d = firstPage.getBBox ();
    int width = (int) r2d.getWidth ();
    int height = (int) r2d.getHeight ();

    Image pdfImage = firstPage.getImage(width, height, r2d, null, true, true);

    BufferedImage imageToSave = (BufferedImage) pdfImage;

    File outputFile = new File("public/pdfpreview/" + someName + ".png");
    ImageIO.write(imageToSave, "png", outputFile);  //Trying to delay this part so that it can finish writing to disk
    Thread.sleep(2000)  //If I put this code here, it fixes my problem.     
}
```

Comment: UserB shouldn't experience the delay, since `Thread.sleep` only affects the current thread

Comment: How do you write the file to the disk? If you are using an OutputStream, try to flush() and close() it. After those operations, the file should be present.

Comment: Use an `ExecutorService` and a `Map` with `Future`s as values

Comment: @Matthias, I am using ImageIO.write. I didn't think about flush/close. I will give that a try.

Comment: @fge, Could you write that up in a (more detailed) answer?  Why would that be better than using `join`?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen What you say is true, but if the server has any sort of real traffic then having a thread.sleep in one of the threads will affect performance of the server. For instance tomcat only has so many service threads, if they are all in the middle of a thread.sleep then the next request will have to wait for one of those service threads to free up before it is serviced, even if the newest request has nothing to do with uploading a pdf file.

Comment: @Matthias I tried pdfImage.flush(), imageToSave.flush(), raf.close(), fc.close() and none of them fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say UserA uploads a file while UserB browses normally. After
>   UserA uploads a file, does UserB experience the 2 second delay?

UserB will only experience a delay if UserB's and UserA's requests are being handled by the same thread, which is not the case since most web servers use a separate thread to handle each connection.

> Thread.sleep(2000) be the best code to use?

No, this is probably not a good way of doing things.  Aside from tying up the cpu, you are explicitly having the thread wait 2 seconds before attempting to access the file when you have no guarentee that the file will be ready at that point.  It would be better to try leverage Java's wait() and notify() [Object methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) for concurrency.  However, I do not know if that is necessariy since you should know when the write to disk is complete (a java method will return).

Comment: How can I tell if the write to disk is complete though?

Comment: Yes added it in the original post.

Comment: You could look at the size of outputFile to make sure it has been written too in your convertPDFtoImage() method and just don't return from the method until you are quite certain the write has occurred.

Comment: I saw this solution from a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842674/is-imageio-write-a-blocking-method/11842771#11842771. It looks like a better solution but it's still using Thread.sleep(). Do you think it's still safe to use that?

Comment: That is what I was proposing in the last comment. It atleast makes sure that the file has written before returning from the method. There could exist a better solution.. but I think that will work just fine.