# Server's Robot Screenshot Thread Blocked After Client InputStream Is Read

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I've written a simple server(java)/client(android)...  i'm capturing a screenshot from the server with Robot and using a socket connection to relay that to the client...  this works fine--exactly one time--but I need to repeat the action at will...

i'm fairly certain if pointed in the right direction i can set up the methods for updating the screenshot--but i don't understand why my thread is hanging...

posting a runnable via handler on the client side only returns a null Bitmap after the initial BitmapFactory.decodeStream call...

I've searched up and down and cannot find a reason for this behavior or any indication how to fix it...

SERVER SCREENSHOT THREAD:

```
 private void screen(final Socket socket){
    Thread Shot1 = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
            System.out.println("entered run");
            try {
            while(true){


                Toolkit defaultToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

                Rectangle shotArea = new Rectangle(defaultToolkit
                    .getScreenSize());

                BufferedImage screenShot = robot
                    .createScreenCapture(shotArea);

                ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", out);


                out.flush();


                Thread.sleep(2000);

            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    };
    Shot1.start();
}
```

CLIENT READ THREAD:

```
 Downloader = new Thread() {

             @Override
             public void run() {
                 android.os.Process
                    .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

                 Bitmap bit = null;
                 try {
                     in = socket.getInputStream();

                 } catch (IOException e1) {
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 try {
                     if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                         Log.i("thread interrupted", "true");
                         throw new InterruptedException();
                     }
                     if (socket != null) {

                         bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                         Log.i("bitmap", "decoded");


                     } else if (socket == null) {
                         Log.i("socket", "null");
                     }

                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

                 if (bit != null && bit != temp //temporary bitmap for comparison only{
                          Log.i("bitmap", "not null and not temp");
                          threadMsg(bit);


                 }

             }

             private void threadMsg(Bitmap bit) {
                 if (bit != null) {
                     Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                     msg.what = NEED_TO_SET_BITMAP_FROM_SCREENSHOT;
                     Bundle b = new Bundle();
                     b.putParcelable("Bitmap", bit);
                     msg.setData(b);
                     mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                 }
             }

         };
```

It hangs at ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", out);

input and output streams are defined as fields in both the client and server, they are initialized on socket connection.

The code is throwing no errors, the server side screenshot thread will take four screenshots, only one gets read by the client then the server thread will hang at the write line...

I'm lost...  help please...

Comment: I haven't encountered a blocking write() method before. Can you be certain that the thread "hangs" at the ImageIO.write() line and provide debug code to show that? Also, how fast does your program send a whole screenshot over the outputstream? I don't know how fast ImageIO can write a whole screenshot to the outputstream. And is your thread actually "hanging," or could it be that it is taking a while to write all the screenshot data?

Comment: While i can't say that the ImageIO.Write method is blocking the thread...  i can say definitively that this is where the thread stops...  i used System.out.println("some comment") after each line of the code to check and see where things are stopping...  there are no exceptions being thrown...   this is my first foray into sockets and i'm cannot honestly say that i am not doing something wrong on the client side that might be completely wrong...  i can say the client side will loop with no problem, i post runnables from another thread and they function but the bitmap always returns null...

Comment: the first decode on the client side takes less than a second...  the server side appears to loop four times (consistently four times) then ceases to progress through the code at the ImageIO.write line...

Comment: checking times in milliseconds between between shot taken and write completed... 1st shot: 780, 2nd shot: 1726, 3rd shot: 1972, 4th shot: 1741, 5th shot: infinite

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the answer to your problem. I can suggest you check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842674/is-imageio-write-a-blocking-method . If that doesn't work as an alternative, you can send the image data manually by not using ImageIO.write() and just send it with your own code through a DataOutputStream.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it...   after doing some research on Bitmapfactory.decodeStream it appears that an input stream may only be utilized once for decoding...  so, I set up three sockets, one that serves for the client output stream, and two that are alternately connected and closed to transfer screenshots...  this works, but i think i should look into other ways of decoding the jpg's for faster transfer rates.... again, thank you for looking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android's BitmapFactory.decodestream(inputstream) method only allows for a single image to be decoded from an input stream;  Though it may not be the most efficient of workarounds I have solved the problem by:

1) cancel the thread containing the input stream and bitmapfactory call

2) using an asynchronous task to reinitialize the socket and call for a new thread to be established to decode new incoming images...

this works but again, I would appreciate any suggestion for how to make the process more efficient, for example how to use other means to decode incoming images